# Laravel .mov validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

In a project I want to upload video. in my request I use 'path' => 'mimes:mp4,mov,avi,mpg,mpeg;quicktime|nullable',

When uploading a .mov video I always get the error "The video path must be a file of type: mp4, mov, avi, mpg, mpeg, quicktime.". The meme type of the video is video/quicktime.

Uploading .mp4 files works perfect, didn't test with other video types yet. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: what is the meme type of the video if the file extension is .mp4??

Comment: The laravel can guess the extension to be ".qt" instead of ".mov". So, you may need to add .qt to the list too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually check for mime-type if the validation is not working for you:

```
$video = Input::file('path');
$mime = $video->getMimeType();

$accepted_mimes = array("video/x-flv", "video/mp4", "application/x-mpegURL", 
                                                      "video/MP2T", "video/3gpp", "video/quicktime", 
                                                      "video/x-msvideo", "video/x-ms-wmv");

if(in_array($mime, $accepted_mimes)) {
    //valid video format begin upload
} else {
       //invalid video mime type
       // return back with errors
       return redirect->back()->withErrors(['msg', 'Invalid video']);
}
```

For a list of all available mime-types [see here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)

Answer (score 0):

.mov Is just a container. So maybe the mime type / codec is still wrong. You should first verify this with a tool like this: https://mediaarea.net/. As a solution to you problem however (which is less secure) you could only verify the extension (pathname).

[image]

Here you see an example of a .mxf file but with an MPEG codec to help you understand that containers do not have only one mime type (and codec) that belongs to it most of the time.

Warning for just validating file extensions: this is very insecure and could lead to all kinds of trouble. Like people uploading php files or other type of files.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $Video= request('PostDetailsVideo');//this is name of posted file
            $rules=[
                'PostDetailsVideo' => 'required|mimetypes:video/x-ms-wmv,video/x-msvideo,video/quicktime,video/3gpp,video/MP2T,application/x-mpegURL,video/mp4,video/x-flv|max:32768'
            ];
            $CheckIsVideo = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
            if($CheckIsVideo->fails()){//this not video
                return response()->json([
                    'Success'=> false,
                ], 200);
            }
            else
                return response()->json([
                    'Success'=> true,
                ], 200);
```